# No mapping for static-resources Spring Boot

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, staticresource

In my Spring-Boot application, js and css files do not work, it says 404 not found.

My html-page includes the following:

```
  <head>  
     <link href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="/static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <script src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/webjars/sockjs-client/sockjs.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/webjars/stomp-websocket/stomp.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/static/js/operations.js"></script>
 </head>
```

I configured resources so:

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableWebMvc
 public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
     @Override
     public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
         registry
               .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
               .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        }
  }
```

But in logs I receive:

```
  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /favicon.ico
  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /favicon.ico
  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js
  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /static/css/style.css
  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /static/js/operations.js
  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /favicon.ico
```

This is the location of static-sources:

[image: sources]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you configure security to allow those requests?

Comment: No. Did not configure security.

Comment: And the contextPath is?

Comment: How could I find out contextPath?

Comment: applicationContext is. "/"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, this handler serves static content from any of `/static, /public, /resources, and /META-INF/resources` directories that are on the classpath. Since `src/main/resources` is typically on the classpath by default, we can place any of these directories there.

This means that your links should look like:

```
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

instead of

```
<link href="/static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: can you remove MvcConfig class and try it?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve issue in my project by using below path

```
href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/static/..."
```

so try using below path

```
href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/static/css/style.css"
```

There may be better way of resolving it but till then this is a quick fix.